# Wrong nodesize in Rgraphviz dot layout

Tags: r, igraph, graphviz, r-graphviz

I have the following graph object saved as a [file](https://gofile.io/?c=zW9W0F) ("Test.txt") and I would like to visualize this graph with Rgraphviz:

```html
# importing data
yo <- agread("Test.txt", layoutType="neato", layout=TRUE)
plot(yo)
```

The neato layout works fine and gives me the expected results. However, if I use the dot layout, the nodesize is way too large

```html
# importing with dot layout
yo <- agread("Test.txt", layoutType="dot", layout=TRUE)
plot(yo)
```

[image: Dot Layout of Rgraphviz with wrong nodesize]

However, if I use this graphviz [website](http://www.webgraphviz.com/) to plot the exact same graph in dot layout, the nodesize is fine.

Is there a way to manually adapt the nodesize in Rgraphviz as well?